# How to correctly align and space in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, matrices

Hello how can I correct this ?

Here's my code. Thank you all
[image]
[image]

Code:

```
\chapter{Méthodes de différences finies}
\section{Conditions initiales de Dirichlet}
\subsection{Algorithme numérique}
On suppose que le domaine d'étude $\Omega = ]0,1[$ et le pas $h=\frac{1}{N+1}$ avec $N \in \mathbb{N^*} $
%representation du domaine
\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{r c l}
-f''(x) + f(x) &=& 10 sin(3x)\quad \forall  x \in ]0,1[\\
f(0)&=&0\\
f(1)&=&sin(3)
\end{array}
\right.
\]
En appliquant la formule de Taylor au 2éme ordre 
\begin{equation}
    f(x_i+h) = f(x_i) + h\times f'(x_i)+ \frac{h^2}{2} \times f''(x_i) + o(h^2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    f(x_i-h) = f(x_i) - h\times f'(x_i)+ \frac{h^2}{2} \times f''(x_i) + o(h^2)
\end{equation}
D'où on obtient la solution du système précédant
\begin{equation*}
    f''(x_i)=\frac{-2f(x_i)+f(x_i+h)+f(x_i-h)}{h^2}
\end{equation*}
\subsubsection{Pour i = 1}
\begin{equation*}
    g(x_1)+\frac{f(x_0)}{h^2}=\frac{(-2+h^2)f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{h^2}
\end{equation*}
\subsubsection{Pour i = N}
\begin{equation*}
    g(x_{N})+\frac{f(x_{N-1})}{h^2}=\frac{(-2+h^2)f(x_{N})-f(x_{N+1})}{h^2}
\end{equation*}
Avec
\begin{equation*}
    g(x_{i})=\frac{(-2+h^2)f(x_{i})-f(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i-1})}{h^2} \quad
    \forall i \in \mathbb{N^*}
\end{equation*}
Donc finalement on aura le système matriciel 
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{aligned}
AU=B \\[2pt] 
\Updownarrow \\[2pt]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{h^2} 
\begin{pmatrix} 2+h^2&-1&0&\dots&\dots&0 \\ -1&2+h^2&-1&\dots&\dots&0\\0&-1&\ddots&\ddots&\dots&0
\\ \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&&\vdots
\\ \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&&\vdots
\\&&&&2+h^2&-1
\\ 0&\dots&\dots&0&-1&2+h^2
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f(x_1)\\f(x_2)\\ \vdots \\ \vdots  \\f(x_{N-2}) \\f(x_{N-1}) \\f(x_N) 
    \end{pmatrix} = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
     g(x_{1})+\frac{f(x_{0})}{h^2}\\g(x_2)\\ \vdots \\ \vdots  \\g(x_{N-2}) \\g(x_{N-1}) \\g(x_{N})+\frac{f(x_{N-1})}{h^2}
    \end{pmatrix}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\subsection{Programmation sur Matlab}strong text
```

Comment: welcome to rex.se! please, copy here your code from editor. image of code not help us (why we should code your document again?). also extend your code to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}. so far i can only say that it seem that your equations are wide than text width.

Comment: Welcome again. Which alignment and space should be corrected for the formulas that have you written?

Comment: @Sebastiano from the AU=B  system and what is below it  thank you.

Comment: @Zarko I'm new here and I really didn't understand what you wanted me to change

Comment: @YassineElAroui At least you should add the code in the screenshot. At best you should add an [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/156344).

Comment: @YassineElAroui Don't worry, we'll help you.

Comment: please prepare a small test document with the same preamble which you use at your real document. in it add code which image you show in question. than try to compile your test document that you will see, if it working. than copy code of this test document and past it in your question, similarly as you do in your (deleted now) answer. that is all what we ask you. than explain what is your problem.

Comment: The matrix equations looks to be too large to fit on line, you should break it at the equals sign.

Comment: As mentioned already by @AndrewSwann, the equation is too wide for the page.  The position of the equation number is the clue that identifies this problem.  Breaking it into two lines, starting with the equals sign on the second line, is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one of many other ways to align the equation.

This example can be adapted to your case

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}                     
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
    A&U&=&B\\[0.25cm]
    %
    &&\Updownarrow& \\[0.25cm]
    %
    \dfrac{1}{h^2}
    \begin{pmatrix} % matrix A
        a&b&c&d\\
        a&b&c&d\\
        a&b&c&d\\
        a&b&c&d\\
    \end{pmatrix}
    %
    &\begin{pmatrix} % vector U
        a\\b\\c\\d
    \end{pmatrix}
    %
    &=
    %
    &\begin{pmatrix} % vector B
       a\\b\\c\\d
    \end{pmatrix}
    %
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal.

1. I use `mathtools`' `psmallmatrix` so that the equation will be not too wide. `Overfull \hbox` should be avoided, even though it is just a warning.
2. IMHO two consecutive `\cdots` or `\vdots` lines are necessary; one is enough.
3. We should not use `\Updownarrow` in this case, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Méthodes de différences finies}
\section{Conditions initiales de Dirichlet}
\subsection{Algorithme numérique}
On suppose que le domaine d'étude $\Omega = ]0,1[$ et le pas $h=\frac{1}{N+1}$ avec $N \in \mathbb{N^*} $
%representation du domaine
\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{r c l}
-f''(x) + f(x) &=& 10 sin(3x)\quad \forall  x \in ]0,1[\\
f(0)&=&0\\
f(1)&=&sin(3)
\end{array}
\right.
\]
En appliquant la formule de Taylor au 2éme ordre 
\begin{equation}
    f(x_i+h) = f(x_i) + h\times f'(x_i)+ \frac{h^2}{2} \times f''(x_i) + o(h^2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    f(x_i-h) = f(x_i) - h\times f'(x_i)+ \frac{h^2}{2} \times f''(x_i) + o(h^2)
\end{equation}
D'où on obtient la solution du système précédant
\begin{equation*}
    f''(x_i)=\frac{-2f(x_i)+f(x_i+h)+f(x_i-h)}{h^2}
\end{equation*}
\subsubsection{Pour i = 1}
\begin{equation*}
    g(x_1)+\frac{f(x_0)}{h^2}=\frac{(-2+h^2)f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{h^2}
\end{equation*}
\subsubsection{Pour i = N}
\begin{equation*}
    g(x_{N})+\frac{f(x_{N-1})}{h^2}=\frac{(-2+h^2)f(x_{N})-f(x_{N+1})}{h^2}
\end{equation*}
Avec
\begin{equation*}
    g(x_{i})=\frac{(-2+h^2)f(x_{i})-f(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i-1})}{h^2} \quad
    \forall i \in \mathbb{N^*}
\end{equation*}
Donc finalement on aura le système matriciel 
\begin{equation*} 
AU=B \Leftrightarrow \begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{h^2} 
\begin{psmallmatrix} 
2+h^2&-1&0&\dots&\dots&0 \\ -1&2+h^2&-1&\dots&\dots&0\\0&-1&\ddots&\ddots&\dots&0
\\ \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&&\vdots
\\&&&&2+h^2&-1
\\ 0&\dots&\dots&0&-1&2+h^2
    \end{psmallmatrix}
    \begin{psmallmatrix}
    f(x_1)\\f(x_2)\\ \vdots \\f(x_{N-2}) \\f(x_{N-1}) \\f(x_N) 
    \end{psmallmatrix} = 
    \begin{psmallmatrix}
     g(x_{1})+\frac{f(x_{0})}{h^2}\\g(x_2)\\ \vdots \\ g(x_{N-2}) \\g(x_{N-1}) \\g(x_{N})+\frac{f(x_{N-1})}{h^2}
    \end{psmallmatrix}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\subsection{Programmation sur Matlab}strong text
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]